# Как написать компаратор для sort?

Tags: c++, сортировка

Здравствуйте! Надо написать программу, которая сортирует фамилии по алфавиту. Началом считается первая большая буква. Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

bool Compare(string name1, string name2)
{
    string temp1 = "";
    string temp2 = "";
    bool b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < name1.length(); i++)
    {
        if ((name1[i] >= 'A')&&(name1[i]<='Z'))
        {
           b = true;
        }
        if (b) temp1 += name1[i];
    }
    b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < name2.length(); i++)
    {
        if ((name2[i] >= 'A') && (name2[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            b = true;
        }
        if (b) temp2 += name2[i];
    }
    if (temp1 == temp2) return true;
    int length;
    if (temp1.length() == temp2.length()) length = temp1.length();
    else length = min(temp1.length(), temp2.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (temp1[i] > temp2[i]) return false;
        if (temp1[i] < temp2[i]) return true;
    }
    return true;
}

void main()
{
    ifstream fin("NAMES.IN");
    string temp;
    getline(fin, temp);
    long N = stoi(temp);
    string *names = new string[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        getline(fin, names[i]);
    sort(names, names + N, Compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << names[i] << endl;
}
```

Работает нормально, пока все фамилии разные. Если есть одинаковые, появляется ошибка "invalid comparator". Подскажите пожалуйста, как его правильно написать, что бы не было этой ошибки.

Comment: А если строка не содержит заглавных букв, что тогда? Или если в строке содержится два слова с заглавной буквой?

Comment: в каждой строке есть заглавная буква. Сколько слов и сколько заглавных букв не важно. Все равно считается как одна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас ошибка в том, что компаратор (это грубо говоря знак меньше) при равных объектах *обязан* возвращать false. Иначе будет нарушено свойство симметричности. И возможно даже зацикливание.

Замените `if (temp1 == temp2) return true;` на `false`. 
И `return true;}` на `return temp1.length() < temp2.length()`.

Тут ещё есть ошибка когда одна фамилия в вашем определении - префикс второй.

И кстати это будет только в отладочной версии программы, когда компилятор (особенно ms vc++) делают вызовы cmp(a,b) и cmp(b,a). В релизе такой ошибки не будет. Но может быть выход за границы массива или зацикливание.

Comment: Эээ... Компаратор - это, грубо говоря, отношение **меньше**, так что при равных он должен возвращать `false`...

Comment: @Harry да) ну я и сформулировал)